# How do I output the top 5 results with the highest value in column ArticleViews

Tags: c#, sql, select

Below is my data source.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="getbyviews" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectAntiFrack %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [ArticleID], [ArticleTitle], [ArticlePublished], [ArticleViews] 
FROM [ArticlesTBL] 
WHERE ([ArticlePublished] = @ArticlePublished) 
ORDER BY [ArticleViews] DESC">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="True" Name="ArticlePublished" Type="Boolean" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there a way to manipulate the select statement to only grab the 5 highest results? Or can this be done in C#?
My datasource will be used later to populate a listview.

Comment: You may get more than 5 if there are ties using top.  How would you want to handle ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `TOP 5`:

```
SELECT TOP 5 [ArticleID], [ArticleTitle], [ArticlePublished], [ArticleViews] 
FROM [ArticlesTBL] 
WHERE ([ArticlePublished] = @ArticlePublished) 
ORDER BY [ArticleViews] DESC
```